# Ubuntu booting error

Tags: boot

I installed windows 7 64bit version to my desktop and next i tried to install ubuntu! But when installing Ubuntu installer didn't recognize any operating system on my computer! What should I do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repair window 7 after reparing, log into the windows system and run Ubuntu installer form inside the system this would help it detecting windows